# passing void pointer as parameter

Tags: c, void-pointers, c89

So i'm trying to get value according to my sort function in function like this.

```
void * getBest(void *t, unsigned int n, unsigned int bytes, int (*vrt)(void *, void *)) {
  int i = 0;
  int returnI = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(i != returnI) {
    if(vrt(t[i], t[returnI]) == 1)  
    {
      returnI = i;
    }
    }
  }
  return t[returnI];
}
```

Using sorting function like this:

```
int pieni_dbl(void *a, void *b)
{
  double *ad = a;
  double *bd = b;
  return *ad < *bd;
}
```

And calling it like this

```
  double *parasDbl = getBest(dt, 6, sizeof(double), pieni_dbl);
  short int *parasShort = getBest(st, 10, sizeof(short int), iso_itseis_short);
```

but it gives error: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpedantic]
if(vrt(t[i], t[paras]) == 1)

Why is that? Is it possible somehow to pass void pointer to as parameter to function which compares it in ANSI c?

Comment: See where **exactly** you get that error. Then think how the compiler shall do know which type the `void *` points to when you dereference it.

Comment: And don't use C89 or C90 in new code! It is obsolete since >17 years now.

Comment: Yeah i know that ANSI c is obsolete nowadays but i have to use it now and error is coming in  if(vrt(t[i], t[returnI]) == 1)  that line and i have no idea what causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `t` has type `void *`, it is wrong twice- (or thrice-)over to perform the function call ...

```
vrt(t[i], t[returnI])
```

..., as you do.

In the first place, consider the expression `t[i]`: what is its type?  Its type is `void`, of course.  That's not the correct type for the corresponding function parameter (nor even an allowed type for a function parameter).

The compiler doesn't even get around to complaining about that, but consider the implications.  Since `t[i]` has type `void`, how could the program even go about trying to compute it?  How large is a `void`? In fact, it is undefined, and C forbids performing arithmetic on a `void *`.

Perhaps you're saying "Ok, but where's the arithmetic"?  Well, C defines array indexing in terms of pointer arithmetic.  Your expression `t[i]` is equivalent to `*(t + i)` -- voila, forbidden arithmetic with a `void *`.

Comment: Okay i see actually why is that happening thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the form `a[i]` is shorthand for `*(a + i)`. Thus, you're writing

```
if(vrt(*(t + i), *(t + returnI)) == 1)
```

But that involves dereferencing a `void *`, which is prohibited.

Comment: more to the point, it involves doing `+` on a `void *`